# Locating a paper in Euler's complete works

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

I'm currently reading Disquisitiones Arithmeticae and I keep seeing references to Euler such as "Comm. acad. Petrop., 8 [1736], 1741, 141". My question: How can I go about locating this paper in http://eulerarchive.maa.org/ ? (Note: I want to know how to do it myself so an explanation would help - thanks!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I imagine that *Petrop.* is short for *Petropolis*, literally, the city of Peter, so, presumably St. Petersburg.  In the archive, the first section of the [search by publication](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/publications/index.html) is "St. Petersburg Academy Publications", and the first publication is called *Commentarii*.  That fits "Comm. acad. Petrop."; the table of contents for volume 8 (1736, published 1741) lists a few papers by Euler, one on page 141, all of which fits the citation.

(The table of contents actually gives the author of the paper starting on page 141 as *Eiusdem*; this means "of the same person" in Latin, similar to *ibidem* in modern bibliographies.  You might be able to guess this from context.)

Comment: Thanks for the Latin corrections, @Mico

Comment: Presumably you are pointing at [E54 -- Theorematum quorundam ad numeros primos spectantium demonstratio](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E054.html) with links to the [original text](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/docs/originals/E054.pdf) and [a parallel translation](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/docs/translations/E054tr.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

I would start by looking at the dates - this was published in 1741, on page 141 of Comm. Acad. Petrop., 8.

A quick perusal yields E54 -- Theorematum quorundam ad numeros primos spectantium demonstratio

Comment: http://eulerarchive.maa.org -> Date -> Date Published -> 1741 yields 10 papers E046-E056, listed in order of page number...